# Multirow vertical positioning

Tags: tables, multirow, booktabs

I can't specify the vertical position of my multirow content.
The following compiles fine:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{p{3cm}ccc}
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}{3cm}{Cat cat cat cat cat cat cat}
        &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Food}\\
        \cmidrule{2-4}
        & A&B&C\\
        \midrule
        D & 123 & 456 & 789\\\addlinespace
        E & 123 & 456 & 789\\\addlinespace
        F & 123 & 456 & 789\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

But when I add `[b]` to the multirow it gets messed up:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{p{3cm}ccc}
        \toprule
        \multirow[b]{2}{3cm}{Cat cat cat cat cat cat cat}
        &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Food}\\
        \cmidrule{2-4}
        & A&B&C\\
        \midrule
        D & 123 & 456 & 789\\\addlinespace
        E & 123 & 456 & 789\\\addlinespace
        F & 123 & 456 & 789\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

According to [the multirow documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/multirow/multirow.pdf) the syntax should be fine...

Comment: In my opinion there is no need for [`multirow`](//ctan.org/pkg/multirow) here. You can place `Cat` in the lower header row - [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeRBL.png).

Comment: Yes, in the MWE with reduced content that would do the job. But it's not perfoming as per documentation - is that a bug?

Comment: I updated the MWE to make the problem more apparent.

Comment: I cannot detect any difference in output between the versions with and without the `[b]` option.

Comment: Hmm.. for me the version with `[b]` won't compile at all. I get an error `Missing number, treated as zero. \multirow[b]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

use of rules from `booktabs` add some vertical space which `multirow` can not compensate automatically for such and similar cases `multirow` has possibility to manual adjusting content position:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{p{3cm}ccc}
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}{=}[-0.5ex]{Cat cat cat cat cat cat cat}% [-0.tex] is manual adjusting of posititon
          &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{Food}  \\
        \cmidrule{2-4}
          &  A  &  B  &   C             \\
        \midrule
        D & 123 & 456 & 789             \\\addlinespace
        E & 123 & 456 & 789             \\\addlinespace
        F & 123 & 456 & 789             \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get the feeling that something's wrong with my setup. I get the same error as stated above with your code: `Missing number, treated as zero. ...{2}{=}[-0.5ex]{Cat cat cat cat cat cat cat}`.
I run pdfLaTeX. From the log file: `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.9.28) `

Comment: hm, it seems that you not have recent `multirow` package ... it  should be version v2.2 from 2016/11/25,

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from the vertical padding around `\cmidrule`. You have to make a correction for this.

I propose another solution, just in case you don't really need a `p` column type; with the `makecell` package, you can break lines inside standard cells. I wrote a code that gives the same result with `\multirowcell`  and a manual line-breaking:

```
\documentclass[border = 3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow, makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}ccc}
  \toprule
  \multirow[b]{2}{3cm}[-\dimexpr\aboverulesep + \belowrulesep + \cmidrulewidth]{Cat cat cat cat cat cat cat}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Food} \\
  \cmidrule{2-4}%
    & A & B & C \\
  \midrule
  D & 123 & 456 & 789 \\\addlinespace
  E & 123 & 456 & 789 \\\addlinespace
  F & 123 & 456 & 789 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\qquad\renewcommand\cellalign{bl}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
  \toprule\
  \ & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Food} \\
  \cmidrule{2-4}%
  \multirowcell{-2}{Cat cat cat cat \\ cat cat cat} & A&B&C\\
  \midrule
  D & 123 & 456 & 789 \\\addlinespace
  E & 123 & 456 & 789 \\\addlinespace
  F & 123 & 456 & 789 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I accepted Zarko's answer, since it solved the specific problem. However, I really like the solution using ´makecell´, which I am actually using now due simplicity